# ORDER BY [PRIMARY_KEY] has to apply sort-order when it should simply use the index?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

according to my Research, ordering by the Primary key (or on any other column with an index) - the query should run without an explicit sort.

I also found a blog where this behavior was shown on different databases, one of them being Oracle.

However - in my Tests it this was not true - what could be the reason? Bad install-options? Broken Index? (although I ruled that out by creating a completely new table)

the query:

```
select * from auftrag_test order by auftragkey
```

the execution plan:

```
 Plan Hash Value  : 505195503 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation            | Name         | Rows   | Bytes    | Cost  | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |              | 167910 | 44496150 | 11494 | 00:00:01 |
|  1 |   SORT ORDER BY      |              | 167910 | 44496150 | 11494 | 00:00:01 |
|  2 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | AUFTRAG_TEST | 167910 | 44496150 |  1908 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
create table AUFTRAG_TEST
(
   auftragkey           VARCHAR2(40) not null,
  ...
);
alter table AUFTRAG_TEST
  add constraint PK_AUFTRAG_TEST primary key (AUFTRAGKEY);
```

you might ask yourself why the Primary key would be a varchar field. Well,  this is something our bosses have decided. (Actually we put in stringified guids)

The blog I found:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by

P.S.: I think that I found out the Problem. This select does NOT "order by":

```
select * 
from auftrag_test 
where auftragkey = 'aabbccddeeffaabbccddeeffaabbccdd' 
order by auftragkey
```

So - apparently - it does ONLY work, if you filter against an index, with "equality" which wouldn't be very helpful at all.

P.P.S: MS-SQL seems to do just what I expected. If I order by the Primary key (with a non clustered unique index) - the sort is "free". In execution plan, and also query time wise.

Comment: Please post some code and the explain plans to clarify your question. Also, please give some references about what you found by searching

Comment: You are selecting **all** rows and columns. The optimizer things that doing an index lookup for each of the 167910 rows to get the proper sort order is more expensive then sorting those rows in memory - and the optimizer is probably correct about that.

Comment: Of source the second select does not need to use an `order by`. The optimizer knows that the `where` condition can only return exactly one row - no need to sort that result at all

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that scanning a big table through an index might take hours Vs. full table scan on the same table that will take only few minutes.
In this case travesing through the index is order to save a O(n*log(n)) sort operation, doesn't sound like a good idea.

---

Heap table will yield sort operation.
IOT (Index orginized Table, also knows as "clustered index") is already sorted.

---

```
create table t_heap (i int primary key,j int);
create table t_iot  (i int primary key,j int) organization index;
```

---

```
select * from t_heap order by i;
```

[image]

```
select * from t_iot order by i;
```

[image]